# Google Calender Vr3 - How do I add a reminder to an event?

Tags: vb.net, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

So far I am able to insert an event in a calendar using the following code.

```
    Dim calService As CalendarService = calendarFunctions.getCalendarService(txtrefreshToken.Text.Trim)
    Dim calEventEntry As New Data.Event
    calEventEntry.Summary = "Invoice #123456 Due on dd/mm/yyyy"
    calEventEntry.Description = "Client: Acme Printing Ltd."
    calEventEntry.Id = "inv5670010"

    Dim eventStartDT As New Data.EventDateTime()
    eventStartDT.DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24)
    Dim eventStartEndDT As New Data.EventDateTime()
    eventStartEndDT.DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(25)
    calEventEntry.Start = eventStartDT
    calEventEntry.End = eventStartEndDT
    Dim er As New EventsResource(calService)
    Dim erResp As Data.Event = er.Insert(calEventEntry, txtactiveCal.Text.Trim).Execute()

    'SO FAR SO GOOD!
    'Add email reminder to event 
    Dim remR As New EventReminder()
    remR.Method = "email"
    remR.Minutes = 10
    erResp.Reminders.Overrides.Add(remR) ' <<< ERROR: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

In the last block I am trying to add the reminder to the event (I unserstand this must be done after the event has been created?) . On the last line I get the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this in the end by creating a `List(of EventReminder)` object adding the desired reminder and binding this to the `Overrides` property for `event.reminders`. Hopefully this code may be of help to others.

```
    Dim eventReminder As New List(Of EventReminder)()
    eventReminder.Add(New EventReminder() With { _
         .Minutes = 10, _
         .Method = "email" _
    })

    Dim de As New Data.Event.RemindersData()
    de.UseDefault = False
    de.[Overrides] = eventReminder

    calEventEntry.Reminders = de

    Dim er As New EventsResource(calService)
    Dim erResp As Data.Event = er.Insert(calEventEntry, txtactiveCal.Text.Trim).Execute()

    Response.Write("Event ID: " & erResp.Id & "<br/>")
    Response.Write("Link: <a href=""" & erResp.HtmlLink & """>" & erResp.HtmlLink & "</a><br/>")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect Overrides to be null by default so you can't add anything in there unless you initialize them.