# Setting reminders in google calendar through .net api

Tags: asp.net, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am writing an asp.net webpage that creates events in google calendar. I want to add a "notification" to the event that will send an email 30 minutes before the event begins. 
Reading through the api, I see that there is an attribute for inserting events called "reminders" that seems to be the same thing. Using google's api playground, I can successfully create the event and specify the reminder.
However, using the .net api version 1.9.0.990 I can create the event, but no reminders are set for it. Below is the code I have written:

```
Shared Sub eventWithReminder(calendarIdentifier As String, startTime As DateTime, endTime As DateTime, eventTitle As String)
    Dim calendarID As String


    Dim calList As CalendarList = RoomReservations_RoomReservationsServiceAccount.calService.CalendarList.List().Execute
    For Each Calendar In calList.Items
        If Calendar.Id = calendarIdentifier Then
            calendarID = Calendar.Id
        End If
    Next

    Dim anotherNewEvent As New [Event]
    anotherNewEvent.Summary = eventTitle
    Dim edtStart As New EventDateTime
    edtStart.DateTime = startTime
    Dim edtEnd As New EventDateTime
    edtEnd.DateTime = endTime
    anotherNewEvent.Start = edtStart
    anotherNewEvent.End = edtEnd

    Dim reminder As New EventReminder
    reminder.Method = "email"
    reminder.Minutes = 30
    Dim reminderList As New List(Of EventReminder)
    reminderList.Add(reminder)
    Dim remindData As New [Event].RemindersData
    remindData.UseDefault = False
    remindData.Overrides = reminderList
    anotherNewEvent.Reminders = remindData

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False

    RoomReservations_RoomReservationsServiceAccount.calService.Events.Insert(anotherNewEvent, calendarID).Execute()

End Sub
```

I then view the event in the google calendar web interface, but the Notifications section reads "No notifications set"

Is this functionality not yet built in to the api?
If it is, am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: Reminders are supported in the dotnet library. Take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234296/google-calender-vr3-how-do-i-add-a-reminder-to-an-event

Comment: @luc I tried the code in the answer you linked, but it yields the same result. The event is created in google calendar, but there are no reminders set in it.

Comment: If you correctly set UseDefaults=false then is it possible you are inserting the events using one account and reading it using another? Would you mind pasting the whole code?

Comment: I am not reading the event within the code. I check the event in the google calendar web interface. I will update my question with some more information.

Comment: Indeed, is the account you are checking the event with the same as the account you used to insert the event?

Comment: It is. I am inserting the events using a service account under the same email address that I am using to check the web interface.

Comment: "service account" is the keyword here. You will not be able to add reminders to events created by a service account. You need OAuth2 credentials of the user to achieve that.

Comment: Thank you for your help! That is good to know. Would you mind creating an official answer so that others can see it too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reminders are tied to the authenticated user. In this case Bob was creating events using service account but on user's calendar. Service accounts do not have privileges to modify reminders for users.

In order to change reminders for someone, you need to be authenticated as that person (use their Oauth token).